# how to optimize the Fourier transformation with python

Tags: python, fft

i'm working in a machine learning project in which i want to extract a device power consumption signature here is an example [image]

then i want to extract features using harmonic analysis from that signature , so first, I did the Fourier transformation and i got those for the signature that i already showed to you
[image]
my problem is that i think that this transformation is not so much significant, how can I optimize or ameliorate the transformation,
here is the code that i used to transform the signal

```
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(dt,pt,'k-')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('amplitude')
Fs = 3000
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
n = len(pt)                       # length of the signal
k = np.arange(n)
T = n/Fs
frq = k/T # two sides frequency range
freq = frq[range(int(n/2))]           # one side frequency range

Y = np.fft.fft(pt)/n              # fft computing and normalization
Y = Y[range(int(n/2))]

plt.plot(freq, abs(Y), 'r-')
```

and here is another example [image]
thank you in advance